# Graphql federation vs schema stitching. When to pick one over the other

Tags: graphql, graphql-tools, graphql-federation

I'm new to both concepts so excuse me if it's opinion-based. Currently, I'm looking at Apollo Federation and schema stitching provided by the graphql-tools package, though I guess it applies to similar packages. Could something like a table be created describing certain requirements/conditions to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

[Apollo's GraphQL Federation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/) and "[schema stitching](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching/docs)" both accomplish a similar goal: unify multiple GraphQL APIs under a single GraphQL API.

Based on my understanding, the main differences between them are:

| [Apollo's Federation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/) | [Schema stitching](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching/docs) |
| --- | --- |
| subgraph services own the logic for linking shared types together | the gateway owns the logic for linking shared types together |
| distributes the ownership of subgraphs to the individual service teams | assumes centralized responsibility of the full schema |
| tightly coupled to the Apollo ecosystem | more open source |

For more details, I'd recommend reading https://product.voxmedia.com/2020/11/2/21494865/to-federate-or-stitch-a-graphql-gateway-revisited.